# Oauth 2.0 on appspot.com

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, oauth-2.0

I have a GAE/GWT server web application using [OAuth 2.0](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html).

Locally (GWT development mode) it works fine (user is being redirected to the access confirmation page, I get a token and I can call google API using this token).

But when I deploy the application to appspot, it fails. Confirmation page looks differently, token returns in different format and google API doesn't work with this token.

Does appspot support OAuth 2.0? Does anybody experience this?

Comment: We need more details. Are you using the built-in oauth functionality? Which provider are you using? In what way does the confirmation page "looks differently", how is the token different, and what errors do you get?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Appspot does not suport OAuth http://groups.google.com/group/opendatakit/browse_thread/thread/45ecd1401867154f/0b83b359c2504a74?show_docid=0b83b359c2504a74[1](http://groups.google.com/group/opendatakit/browse_thread/thread/45ecd1401867154f/0b83b359c2504a74?show_docid=0b83b359c2504a74)

Comment: @Mauricio when the question was asked, it didn't support. Downvoting an answer based on changed circumstances just don't add up

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling a lot to find out the issue.

In my case I had normally set my appspot url on the console as an authorized URI just as the localhost one, downloaded the json file and had the same `redirect_uri_mismatch` error.

The solution was to set an `http` version of the url. For some reason, it won't work if you set only the https one.